# All local ports are saying that are closed when i try to use firebase emulator, changing port or anything doesn't do anything

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

[killing ports doesn't help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfwym.png)

Like I tried everything, restarting computer after everything setup database, setup emulators, setup firestore, uninstalling whole firebase and downloading it once again, changing ports in firebase, json, every time I try firebase emulators:start, it says:

```html
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub, storage
  functions: Using node@16 from host.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator
!  Firestore Emulator has exited upon receiving signal: SIGINT
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub
!  database: Port 9000 is not open on 192.168.1.25, could not start Database Emulator.
!  database: To select a different host/port, specify that host/port in a firebase.json config 
file:
      {
         ...

        "emulators": {

          "database": {

            "host": "HOST",

            "port": "PORT"

          }
        }
      }
}
```

also when I try Firebase apps:list, it doesn't show my app at all on list and when i run firebase emulators:start, it shows that port is used only for some time by node.exe, and after short while it disappears
[resource monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2jD5.png)

Comment: When you run `lsof -i :9000` (Linux) what does it say? If you specify a different port (9001 or 9002?) in the firebase.json does it work on that port instead?

Answer (score 1):

I was using someone's else program and it turned out that i just had to change IP address to mine in firebase.json